Calculating the fibres of a scheme morphism are proper but the morphism is not proper
$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}\newcommand{\A}{\mathbb A}$
Let $f:\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb A^1_\mathbb C$ be induced by the ring homomorphism $t\mapsto t^2$, and consider $f|_{U}:U\rightarrow \mathbb A^1_\mathbb C$, where $U$ is $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C\smallsetminus \{\langle t-1\rangle\}$. I am trying to calculate the fibres of this morphism over closed points, and show that these are proper but that $f|_U:U\rightarrow \A^1_\C$ is not proper.
Via some tensor product calculations, and by knowing that $U$ is the distinguished open corresponding to $t-1$, I can calculate the fibres to be:
$$f|_U^{-1}(z)=\begin{cases}
V(t^2-z)\cong \Spec \C\times \C&\text{if }z\neq 1,0\\
V(t^2)\cong \Spec \C[t]/\langle t^2\rangle&\text{if }z=0\\
V(t+1)\cong \Spec \C&\text{if }z=1
\end{cases}$$
which follow because $\C[t]\otimes_{\C[t]}\otimes \C\cong \C[t]/\langle t^2-z\rangle$, so the fibre of $f$ over $z$ is just $V(t^2-z)$, and so the fibre of $f|_U$ is just $U_{t-1}\cap V(t^2-z)$. For $z\neq1$ we have that this completely contained in $U_{t-1}$, so the fibre are the same as they would be in the non restricted case, that is just $V(t^2-z)$. With $z=1$, we have that $V(t^2-1)$ is not completely contained in $U_{t-1}$, so $V(t^2-1)=V'(t^2-1)$, where $V'(t^2-1)$ is the vanishing locus of the ideal $\langle t^2-1\rangle\subset \C[t]_{t-1}$. Since $t-1$ is invertible, this is the vanishing locus of $V(t+1)$ in $\Spec C[t]_{t-1}$, and the so this is isomorphic to $\Spec \C$.
I guess these are also proper because if we write $g_z$ as $f|_U$ restricted to the fibre over $z$ then these are all closed embeddings, and closed embeddings are proper.
What I am confused about is how to prove that $f|_U:U\rightarrow \A^1$ is not proper. The morphism is not closed becasue every closed subset of $\A^1$, and thus of $U$ is a finite set of closed points, and $f|_U$ takes closed points to closed points. We thus have to go to the base change, but I am not sure what I should base change by because the simple base changes don't really change anything or leave me with closed embeddings as above. Any help would be appreciated.

It is enough to note that the localization $\mathbb{C}[t]_{(t-1)}$ is not finitely generated as module over $\mathbb{C}[t^2]$ (because pushforwards of coherent sheaves under proper morphisms are coherent). Indeed, the submodule generated by a finite set of elements
$$
\frac{f_1(t)}{(t-1)^{n_1}}, \dots, \frac{f_k(t)}{(t-1)^{n_k}}
$$
(where $f_i(t)$ are polynomials) does not contain $\tfrac{1}{(t-1)^{n}}$ for any $n > \max\{n_i\}$.

Why is the push forward of a coherent sheaf but a proper morphism coherent?

This is one of the most important properties of proper morphisms, you can find it in any algebraic geometry textbook (e.g., in Hartshorne).

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$This can be done using the valuative criterion for properness. Take the valuation ring $R = \mathbb C[t]_{(t-1)}$ with quotient field $K = \mathbb C(t)$. Let $\iota: \Spec K \to \mathbb A^1$ be the natural inclusion as the generic point. The composition $f\circ \iota: \Spec K \to \mathbb A^1$ then corresponds to the ring map
$$\mathbb C[s] \to\mathbb C(t),\ s \mapsto t^2.$$
Hence it factors over $\mathbb C[s] \to \mathbb C[t]_{(t-1)}=R, s \mapsto t^2$, leading to a morphism $\Spec R \to \mathbb A^1$, so that we have a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\Spec K @>\iota>> \mathbb A^1\\
@V  V V @VV f V\\
\Spec R @>>> \mathbb A^1
\end{CD}
Since $f$ is proper (it is finite), there exists a unique diagonal arrow $g:\Spec R \to \mathbb A^1$ fitting into the diagram. This arrow is given by inclusion
$$\mathbb C[t] \subset R.$$
Clearly, the closed point of $\Spec R$ gets mapped to the point which corresponds to the prime ideal $(t-1)$. If you now replace $\mathbb A^1$ by $U$ in the upper right corner, you still get a commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
\Spec K @>\iota>> U\\
@V  V V @VV f|_U V\\
\Spec R @>>> \mathbb A^1
\end{CD}
But since the diagonal map $g$ was unique, and does not factor over $U$, there is no diagonal arrow this time. Hence $f|_U$ is not proper.

How is $\mathbb C[t]_{t-1}$ a DVR? It has multiple maximal ideals, i.e. every maximal ideal that is not of the form $t-1$.

@Chris That's notational confusion: By $\mathbb C[t]_{(t-1)}$ I mean the localisation of $\mathbb C[t]$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak p = (t-1)$. This has a single maximal ideal generated by $t-1$. It is the local ring of $\mathbb A^1$ at the point which corresponds to $\mathfrak p$.

Got you thank you @red_trumpet
